# How to update QCustomPlot Data in thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qcustomplot

I want to display real time data with help of QCustomPlot in c++ . so I do this:

in header file:

```
class QtGuiApplication : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
QtGuiApplication(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);


private:
Ui::QtGuiApplicationClass ui;

//plot
QCustomPlot*        plot_;
std::thread thread_Displayer_;
bool thread_run_flag_ = false;
void thread_Displayer_fn();

};
```

and in source file I use a push Button to start thread and ... like this:

```
void     QtGuiApplication::btn_Display_clicked()
{

if (thread_run_flag_)
{
    ui.btn_Dispaly->setText("Display");
    thread_run_flag_ = false;
    if (thread_Displayer_.joinable())
    {
        thread_Displayer_.join();
    }
}
else
{
    thread_run_flag_ = false;
    if (thread_Displayer_.joinable())
    {
        thread_Displayer_.join();
    }
    ui.btn_Dispaly->setText("Stop");
    thread_run_flag_ = true;
    thread_Displayer_ = std::thread(&QtGuiApplication::thread_Displayer_fn, 
      this);
}


}

void     QtGuiApplication::thread_Displayer_fn()
{
double y_max_ = 0;
double y_min_ = 0;
while (thread_run_flag_)
{
    QVector<double> x(16384), y(16384); 
    for (int i = 0; i<16384; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = i; 
        y[i] = x[i]; 
        if (y[i] > y_max_)
            y_max_ = y[i];
        if (y[i] < y_min_)
            y_min_ = y[i];
    }

    plot_->yAxis->setRange(y_min_, y_max_);
    plot_->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
    plot_->replot();
    
   }

  }
```

but This error occurs when I start the code:

> "cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread"

How can I solve it?

Comment: With the given code we can not test and reproduce your problem. However, I think you have to `emit`a signal from the `thread_Displayer_fn()` and connect it to a function in your main GUI that receives the data and updates the plot.

Comment: Is it necessary for this method, I create a new class and emit a signal from object of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to (or at least this is how it works for me) create a signal that will be emitted every iteration of the for loop in your thread. Then, connect this signal to a slot that will do the actual update of the data

```
class QtGuiApplication : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QtGuiApplication(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QtGuiApplication();
private slots:
    void setPlotData(QVector<double> x,QVector<double> y);
    void pushButtonClicked();
signals:
    void newData(QVector<double> x, QVector<double> y);
private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplication *ui;
    QCustomPlot* plot_;
    std::thread thread_Displayer_;
    bool thread_run_flag_ = false;
    void thread_Displayer_fn();
};

double fRand(double fMin, double fMax){
    double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}

QtGuiApplication::QtGuiApplication(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::QtGuiApplication)
{
    // Set up UI
    ui->setupUi(this);
    plot_ = ui->qcustomplot;

    // Register data type for signals
    qRegisterMetaType<QVector<double>>("QVector<double>");

    // Prepare graph
    plot_->addGraph();

    // Connect
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(pushButtonClicked()));
    connect(this,SIGNAL(newData(QVector<double>,QVector<double>)),this,SLOT(setPlotData(QVector<double>,QVector<double>)));
}

QtGuiApplication::~QtGuiApplication()
{
    delete ui;
}

void QtGuiApplication::pushButtonClicked()
{
    if (thread_run_flag_)
    {
        ui->pushButton->setText("Display");
        thread_run_flag_ = false;
        if (thread_Displayer_.joinable())
        {
            thread_Displayer_.join();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        thread_run_flag_ = false;
        if (thread_Displayer_.joinable())
        {
            thread_Displayer_.join();
        }
        ui->pushButton->setText("Stop");
        thread_run_flag_ = true;
        thread_Displayer_ = std::thread(&QtGuiApplication::thread_Displayer_fn,
          this);
    }
}

void QtGuiApplication::setPlotData(QVector<double> x, QVector<double> y)
{
    plot_->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
    plot_->rescaleAxes();
    plot_->replot();
}

void QtGuiApplication::thread_Displayer_fn()
{
    while (thread_run_flag_)
    {
        QVector<double> x(ui->spinBox->value()), y(ui->spinBox->value());
        for (int i = 0; i<ui->spinBox->value(); ++i)
        {
            x[i] = i;
            y[i] = fRand(0,10);
        }
        emit newData(x,y);
        usleep(ui->doubleSpinBox->value()*1000);// convert to us
    }
}
```

Note that I also added a `usleep` function after the emmit. If you do not put it you will not be able to push the button again and stop, I think it is because of the rate at which the data is sent.

[Here](https://github.com/apalomer/qcustomplot_online) you can find the whole example.

Comment: Thank you.  after your comment i did the same thing as you and it works.

Answer (score 0):

make this function static and try `void QtGuiApplication::thread_Displayer_fn()`

```
  static void QtGuiApplication::thread_Displayer_fn()
```

Because object created from class QtGuiApplication already own by main thread and your are trying to call a method of it from another thread (child thread) with the above statement.

Comment: If I make this function static I can't access non static class data members. I need non static members at this function.

Comment: declare  a struct with pointers of all the data type that you want to pass to this static method. Assign the address of all the data types and send that struct object as parameter to this static method and check.